# Как сделать обновлять столбец Mysql не по id а по своему значению

Tags: php, mysql

не могу разобраться.

Есть вот такой код, это система перевода монет от одного пользователя другому.
Все работает хорошо, но мне нужно что бы пользователи делали перевод не по id а по определенному значение в разделе я назвал его "adwallet". К каждому пользователи при регистрации выдается свой 41 значний код состоящий из букв и цифр пример: "r229fa1c22d4686dd370208edb4910829d59901da"

Что мне нужно, что бы пользователь вводил данный код и по нему делал перевод.
Но когда в разделе adwallet есть буквы то мне выдает вот такую ошибку "Error updating record: Unknown column 'r229fa1c22d4686dd370208edb4910829d59901da' in 'where clause'"
Ну а когда есть цифры все работает прекрасно

В mysql строку я настроил так
adwallet - varchar(60) -  utf8_general_ci

Код

```
 $sql = "UPDATE cl_users 
    SET wallet = CASE WHEN adwallet = $sender THEN wallet - $amount
                       WHEN adwallet = $receiver THEN wallet + $amount
                       ELSE wallet
                       END
    WHERE adwallet IN ($sender, $receiver)";
```

У меня есть предположение что что то нужно изменить в этой строке, но что бы я не бы не менял все равно одна и также ошибка

```
WHERE adwallet IN ($sender, $receiver)
```

sender - Адрес отправителя 
receiver - Адрес получателя 
amount - сумма 
wallet - тут хранится баланс пользователя 
adwallet - тут хранится 41 значьный код пользователя по которому нужно делать перевод

Comment: у вас проблема не в том, что нельзя обновить не по id, а в том, что вы вставляете строковое значение в запрос без кавычек `$sender, $receiver`, а СУБД такую вставку интерпретирует как название колонок таблицы, о чём вам и сообщает

Comment: Понял в чем была моя проблема, спасибо большое за подсказку.

Comment: На самом деле проблема в том, что вы в принципе подставляете значения переменных непосредственно в тело запроса. При таком подходе всегда найдется пользователь который задаст что то не корректное, например содержащее кавычки и все сломается (если это будет прошаренный "прользователь" то будет sql-инъекция, которой можно сделать вообще все что угодно с вашей БД). Всегда используйте подстановку значений, предлагаемую драйвером БД (подготовленные запросы), например https://php.ru/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.html (для практически всех языков и всех драйверов БД есть аналоги)

Comment: @itscoldhell , прислушайся к Mike . Переход на пред запросы избавит от большой кучи проблем.